# PyEphem Rise/Set Azimuths for Stars and Constellations

Tags: pyephem

I can't seem to figure out how to calculate an azimuth of a star, let's say Sirius, when it is at alt=0 (star rise/star set).

So essentially in the end I will have two values.

Sirius.az @ star rise
Sirius.az @ star set

Is this possible?

THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply check the `.az` attribute of the star once your observer object has determined the moment of rising or setting. For example:

```
import ephem

s = ephem.star('Sirius')

boston = ephem.Observer()
boston.lat = '42.37'
boston.lon = '-71.03'

boston.next_rising(s)
print s.alt, s.az
boston.next_setting(s)
print s.alt, s.az
```

Running this script at this moment gives me the encouraging output:

```
0:00:00.0 112:23:25.2
0:00:00.0 247:36:34.9
```

As you can see, the rising and setting routines have already established the moment of zero altitude, leaving the azimuth for you to read off and use!